# Kivy add widgets to predefined layout

Tags: layout, insert, kivy, kivy-language

Assuming I have a layout written in kv and I define a `BoxLayout` with an `id` value, how would I later add more widgets into this layout without Kv language? I could do this in python, but I feel like it would be more efficient to do this in Kv language.

Here is some example code (Note: `Widgets` is a `BoxLayout`):

```
<Content@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Button:
        text: 'Test'
    BoxLayout:
        id: to_change
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        Button:
            text: 'Button 1'


<Widgets>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Content:

    # How would I add this button to the layout called "to_change"?
    to_change:
        Button:
            text: 'Button 2'
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking how to do this in `kv` or `python`?

Comment: I would like to do this in kv

Comment: If you want to do this `later`, what triggers `later`? Is it some event?

Comment: It is just if I have, say a custom header widget, and I add this header widget to a screen but want to edit it, so I suppose the trigger is the instantiation of the screen

Comment: If you are talking about something as simple as the `text` for ` Label` or `Button`, you can use a kivy `Property`. For example, in your `Content` class you could have a `StringProperty` named `my_button_text`. Then in the `Button` rule, you can use `text: root.my_button_text`. Any time you want to change the `text` of that `Button`, you only need to change `my_button_text` in the `Content` instance.

Comment: What if I wanted to add a new widget itself, not just edit the text?

Comment: Is this possible to do, or will I have to do this in Python?

Comment: It may be possible, but it would likely involve trying to use some python code inside the `kv` in an obscure way. Just using python would be more straightforward.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer